# How to create a button which call the keyboard but not use or display a TexField?

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, keyboard, textfield

I would like to create a button which is able to call the keyboard with a field like the image below. I wont also to save what I write in a variable to use it.

But I don't want to show a TextField, maybe use it but not display it. I wish it looks like a button.

How can I do? Thanks.

[image]